# Error with a button performing multiple actions

Tags: ios, audio, uibutton

I am trying to play audio and switch views with the same button..

```
- (IBAction)yourbuttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender
{
    //start a background sound
    NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tap2" ofType: @"caf"];
    NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:soundFilePath ];
    myAudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];
    myAudioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1; //infinite loop
    [myAudioPlayer play];

    //for Switch view
    ViewController *nextView = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController2"   
    bundle: Nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextView animated:YES];
}
```

> 2014-03-02 19:07:46.817 Balloon Tap[847:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>
>       'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string 
>       parameter'

When I launch my simulator and click on the play button that performs the action it crashes and in my log it comes up with this error above..

How do I go about fixing this and editing my code?

Comment: Read the error. It tells you the problem. Your `soundFilePath` is `nil`. This means you don't actually have a file named `tap2.caf` in your app bundle.

Comment: Print soundFilePath and fileURL values in console.

Answer (score 0):

It appears soundFilePath is Nil

Try this 
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:stringPath];

This removes the alloc, which may cause you some issues here. Also I'm sure you've checked, but is there an issue with the filename? Does it actually exist in your bundle? I.e is it being compiled with the rest of your code? Make sure that you add that file to your project, and it appears in a "Copy Bundle Resources" build phase in your executable's target in Xcode.

Comment: There is nothing at all wrong with calling `[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:]`.